# Calculate the weak closure of $S_{c_0} = \{x \in c_0 : \|x\|_\infty = 1 \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I need to find the weak closure of this set. First I tried using McKay theorem, but found out that $S_{c_0}$ is not convex. Now I'm totally lost. I've seen proofs online that the weak closure of the unit sphere in a normed space is the unit ball, and I kind of understand the proof, but I wanted to find it specifically for this set. Are there any tips on how to find the weak closure of any given tips that could help me in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\|x\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ so that $|x_n| \leq 1$ for all $n$. Consider $x^{n}=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,1,0,0,....)$. Clearly, $\|x^{n}\|_{\infty} =1$. I claim that $x^{n} \to x$ in the weak topology. For this I have to show that $\sum x_iy_i =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i+y_{n+1}$ for any $(y_i) \in c_0^{*}=\ell^{1}$. This is easy and I will let you prove this. Finally, conclude that the weak closure is the closed unit ball of $c_0$.

Comment: Let's see if I follow this reasoning. We are trying to prove that for every $x\in B_{c_0}$, there is a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset \overline{S_{c_0}}^{w}$, such that $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$. Thus, the unit ball is contained in the weak closure, and since it´s obvious  that the weak closure is contained in the unit ball, we have the equality.

Comment: @Ballanzor Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the ambient space is $l_\infty$. It can be shown that $c_0$ is norm closed and since it is convex it is weak closed. Similarly the norm closed unit ball is convex and hence is weak closed. Let $B$ denote the intersection of $c_0$ and the norm closed unit ball. This is weak closed and so
$\overline{S}^w_{x_0} \subset B$.

Now suppose $x \in B$ and $\|x\|_\infty <1$. Suppose $W$ is a weak open set containing $x$. Then there is some weak open neighbourhood of $x$ of the form $\{ y | | \phi(x-y)| < \epsilon \}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and a finite collection $\phi_1,...\phi_n \in l_\infty^*$. Since $\bigcap_k \ker \phi_k$ has codimension $\le n$, it contains some non zero $d \in c_0$ and we can find a $t$ such that
$\|x+td\|_\infty = 1$. Hence $x \in \overline{S}^w_{x_0} $.

In particular, $\overline{S}^w_{x_0}  = B$.